# How to take the input in Ratchet's chat app from a text box on the webpage instead of the console?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ratchet

I made the chat app from the instructions given here http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world.
But now i wanted to take the input from a text box instead of the conn.send() from the console.
How can i do that using php ?
I was able to redirect the sent message to an html element for eg. a text box. Similarly i wanted to get the input from a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all with HTML5 and Javascript. There is a nice demo [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/html5-and-web-sockets.navId-405068.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i wanted to do so in this chat app by ratchet.
So do you know anything about how to do that ?

Comment: I don't understand. I thought you wanted to send messages to the chat app with a text box?

Comment: See..what this ratchet's chat app takes in input through console where one has to type conn.send('message'); to send the message..
This message i was able to redirect in a chat box.
Now i wanted to take the input from a text box in place of that conn.send() thing in the console.

Comment: If you follow the tutorial and change the websocket url to ws://localhost:8080, it should do just that.

Comment: Copy the html code in the link above. Change the websocket url to ws://localhost:8050. Save it as something.html. Open it in a browser. Click on connect...

Comment: hey i am facing a problem..
i opened the connection the page in two browsers..now when i clicked on connect both connected..but when i clicked send message then it disconnects immediately ..in the one still active i can send messages but there are 0 connections.

Comment: This should probably be posted as another question.